# IntelliJ Android cache build with drawables ignores changes

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a minor issue with the way IntelliJ caches files or builds (not sure about terminology here).

Situation Abstract:

Library module

- DrawableA
- DrawableB

App module

- DrawableA

Assume library images are black and white, App ones are color.
The app shows (correctly) the colorful A.
The app shows (correctly) the black and white B (means its missing).
Now I add an image to App project, Drawable B, in color.

- If you simply press "run" he will keep using black and white B
- If you "rebuild project" he will use the correct one
- If you try "Make" and "Compile" manually on Lib and App NO EFFECT

To clarify, this issue is really special. It only occurs if the DrawableB is NOT present in the App module. If you have it, but the WRONG one, and you update it, it works. I assume its an internal caching of IntelliJ, and he does not recognize that I added a drawable (and he has to use it from the App now, not the LIB). Perhaps its something in the google build of Android projects, not enough info about the internal here...

I know, **the obvious tip is "do a rebuild of the whole project"** - that said, **I have 18 App modules**, each for one App. The rebuild takes forever (on one of our machines without SSD), and its not neccessary. If I change something in e.g. AppX, I only need to rebuild AppX and the Library. But there seems to be no option for it.

Does anyone know a workaround, like deleting BIN or other cache folders via script? Cant split up the modules in different "projects", would loose refactoring capabilities.

Crosspost here, check before wasting time to answer (this site here is more frequented and faster, but this issue is so specific, cant hurt to ask the developers too)
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5446674

Comment: Definitely sounds like an IntelliJ bug.  Maybe worth filing an issue on http://youtrack.jetbrains.net since nobody has replied here or on the devnet site.

Comment: Done (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-79616)

Comment: If you use Libraries I suggest Maven. The Android plugin for Maven  is very good. As is the Maven integration in IntelliJ.

Android-Annotations, Robotium and ViewPagerIndicator, all the important Android tool-kits use Maven. It is the best way to work.

Comment: which version of IntelliJ you are using? I also had a problem, but it disappeared when I upgraded to version 12. before that I helped "force regenerate R.java"

Answer (score 3):

Try to rebuild project. Smtm i have same problem and it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with the new IntelliJ Idea version 12? It seems to handle cached resources pretty well.